# Characteristic class integral: on what manifold does $\int c_1 \wedge w_2 = \int c_1 \wedge c_1$ hold?

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, mathematical-physics, fiber-bundles, characteristic-classes

> Characteristic class integral: when does the equality hold $\int c_1 \wedge w_2 = \int c_1 \wedge c_1$,  on what manifolds?

Here $c_1$ is the first Chern class. Here $w_2$ is the 2nd Stiefel-Whitney class.

I know that on a complex manifold (say ${\mathcal{M}^4}$ here), we have $w_2=c_1 \text{ mod } 2$, and that the following is true: 
$$\exp[i \pi (\int_{\mathcal{M}^4} c_1 \wedge w_2)] = \exp[i \pi (\int_{\mathcal{M}^4} c_1 \wedge c_1)],$$

effectively $[\int_{\mathcal{M}^4} c_1 \wedge w_2] \text{ mod } 2=[\int_{\mathcal{M}^4} c_1 \wedge c_1] \text{ mod } 2$

My question is that on what manifold does
$$(1) \;\;\; [\int_{\mathcal{M}^4} c_1 \wedge w_2] \text{ mod } 2= [\int_{\mathcal{M}^4} c_1 \wedge c_1] \text{ mod } 2?$$
or
$$(2) \;\;\;\int_{\mathcal{M}^4} c_1 \wedge w_2 = \int_{\mathcal{M}^4} c_1 \wedge c_1?$$
hold in general? Just for a complex manifold, or for any manifold?
or
$$(3) \;\;\; \exp[i \pi (\int_{\mathcal{M}^4} c_1 \wedge w_2)] = \exp[i \pi (\int_{\mathcal{M}^4} c_1 \wedge c_1)]?$$

Is there any Reference for a proof on when the equality (1) or (2) or (3) holds?

---

[Note add | Nov 18] : Let us write $c_1=F/2\pi$ where $F=dA$ is the field strength of a U(1) gauge field, so that we have an integration done by treating $c_1$ in terms of a differential form.

Comment: How do you propose to make sense of integrating a mod 2 cohomology class in the first place? Your equations only make sense with cup product of mod 2 classes in the first place.

Comment: @ Ted Shifrin. Thanks for the reply. I add an exponential partition function to have mod 2 well-defined. This can be viewed as a partition function in a quantum field theory.

Comment: @ Ted Shifrin: the integral is that we do integration first, then do mod 2.

Comment: I do not know how to represent $w_2$ by a differential form, so I don't know how to integrate.

Comment: @  Ted Shifrin, thanks and see the note added: [Note add | Nov 18] : Let us write $c_1=F/2\pi$ where $F=dA$ is the field strength of a U(1) gauge field, so that we have an integration done by treating $c_1$ in terms of a differential form.

Comment: Oh, I've spent my long career dealing with Chern classes as differential forms. I'm asking you how you write a Stiefel-Whitney class as a differential form.

Comment: @ Ted Shifrin, thank you for reply and see page 10 of this paper http://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.6659v2.pdf and page 4 of this paper: http://arxiv.org/abs/1405.7689

Comment: @ Ted Shifrin, what if I rewrite the wedge product in terms of the cup product? (that is what I meant.) Can we do the integration on a manifold then?